# KVM - Advantages of Installing From PXE

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have been looking at various ways to install KVM guests and am currently using base install ISOs combined with kickstart files automatically install/configure them, but sometimes use cloning. Looking around the net, I find people [installing from a PXE](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/sect-Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide-Guest_Installation-Installing_guests_with_PXE.html) server instead, but never mention why.

Are there big advantages to using a PXE server rather than a local ISO image?

Comment: IMO, the only advantage of a PXE server is having a central location for the .iso rahter then having to download or transfer the iso to multiple KVM hosts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PXE has a bunch of benefits:

- Works on real servers as well as virtual ones without changing anything, so you need to set-up the infrastructure only once.
- It's easy to automate installations from start to finish (technically possible with DVDs but usually requires more work)
- Once you have the infrastructure set-up, adding a new version of your distribution or some alternative install method is a piece of cake
- No losing of DVDs, USB sticks, etc.
- I find it's faster than installing from local media; my network can provide the packages faster than optical drives and most USB sticks.

Typically you'd set this up so you only pxe-boot an installer, which then downloads the rest of the distro from either the internet or (if you do a very large amount of installs or have really shitty internet) a local mirror.

Comment: From this answer I can only see it as a different approach instead of a benefit. I'm using an on-disk base/net iso, dynamically generated kickstart files (for any combination of packages settings you desire) and a local mirror to serve up the content so I don't have to worry about optical speeds or USB sticks either, and whilst not blazing fast, I can't see it being slower than this alternative.

Comment: Right, if you have something that works for you, there's no reason to change that. I like PXE because I don't have to keep discs around which inevitably I will lose or damage.

Comment: I also just realised I actually forgot two benefits: it scales more easily than using physical media; if you can connect 100 machines to your network at the same time, you can pxe-boot them at the same time. And so of this, you can install or re-install, in-place, large amounts of machines (servers, desktops, doesn't even matter) without having to run around with media.